# Logarithm of a limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

I recently saw the following used without explanation:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln(f(x))) = \ln\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x))\right]
$$

> $f(x)$ was $\cos(x)$ in that particular example

I tried to find a limit law that would cause this relation, but I couldn't find any. Does this relation hold true and if so why? (My level is at multivariable calculus, so please keep it simple.)

P.S.: I found the Limits of Composite Functions Theorem, but that requires the limit to be defined and continuous at that point, and logarithmic functions diverge at infinity.

Comment: The limit of composition and the limit of $f(x)$ need to exist, it does not matter that the log is unbounded at infinity. You can still apply limit of composition law at infinity, see, for example, this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904662/composition-and-limits-at-infinity

Comment: The limit variable is $n$ but the function variable is $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $L:=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$ exists and that $f>0$ on $x>0$:

- if $0<L<\infty$, you can apply the basic cited theorem of composition of limits, as $\log$ is continuous at $L$
- if $L=0$, fix $M < 0$. Define $\epsilon':=e^M$. Find $c>0$ such that for $x>c$ we have $0<f(x)<\epsilon'$. Therefore, for $x>c$, you have $\log(f(x))<M$ and this proves that the limit of the composite function is $-\infty$
- if $L=\infty$  you reason analogously: fix $M>0$, and let $M':=e^M$. Pick $c$ with $x>c \implies f(x)>M'$. You now have $x>c \implies \log(f(x))>M$

As noted by Vasili, all of this can be generalized in a unique theorem, I am showing the mechanics for these special cases, since maybe this helps having a better hold on the definition of limits.

I leave the rest to the OP, for the case $L$ does not exist or $f$ is not positive.

Comment: By , do you mean the Euler's Number to the power of M?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned yourself, The Limit of Composite Functions Theorem answers your question for most cases when the range of $f(x)$ is in the domain of $Ln(x)$, and the limit of $f(x)$ exists.

When $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, it can be easily proved even by the definition of limit that both sides of your identity also equal infinity if you assume that $Ln(\infty)= \infty$.

If the range of $f(x)$ is not positive, your identity is not necessarily ture. For example put $f(x) = - 1/x$, then, the left side of the equation is always undefined, where as the right side is $Ln(0)$, which could be defined to be
-$\infty$ or simply, could be considered undefined.

In any case, as you mentioned, your equation is true when $f(x)$ is defined and positive, and has a limit other than $0$ or $\infty$ by the limit of composite functions theorem since $Ln(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0, \infty)$.